# How to update recyclerview after view was created with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having a hard time to understand this thing about updating the main thread. So basically I have a ReciclerView inside my fragment and it works fine but ONLY if the layout is loaded for the first time. I was trying to implement the `SwipeRefreshLayout` just in case the phone wasn't connected to the internet, the user would refresh the page, but the Recycler doesn't work!

The Call :

```
pullToRefresh = root.findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.push);
    pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
        presenter?.netWorkCall();

    }
```

The Response :

```
override fun showResponse(data: List<CategoryModel>) {
    if(data.isEmpty()){
        waringText.text = "N/A"
        waringText.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        waring.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
    }else{
        pullToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL ,false)
        recyclerView.adapter = MainCategoryAdapter(data,findNavController());
    }
}
```

How can I update this thing ?

Comment: Not enough information in question.  have you tried debugging the code ? View creation is not a problem here .

Comment: I already said, I have a list and I wanna update the items from the API, the problem is, when the View is already created with NO data inside of the RecyclerView it doesn't update the list after trying to refresh the page! it doesn't show anything on debugging, when it hits the adapter , the view doesn't start, I put a breakpoint inside of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the adapter to the recyclerView only once and for the next times you should call `recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
but what I'm seeing from you code above, you are setting the adapter again and maybe it's the cause of this problem.
use this code:

```kotlin
override fun showResponse(data: List<CategoryModel>) {
    if(data.isEmpty()){
        waringText.text = "N/A"
        waringText.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        waring.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
    }else{
        pullToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        if (recyclerView.adapter == null){
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL ,false)
            recyclerView.adapter = MainCategoryAdapter(data,findNavController())
        }else{
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same thing. the recycler view doesn't show up. I never had that problem with Java.

Comment: maybe I don't know solution of your problem but I'm sure that it's not about language you pick for programming